# Insert a new record in a separate database stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am having two databases. When a new customer record is added into fDebtor table in database ABC, a new record should be appended in fDebtor table in database DEF as well.

Can some one help me to write a stored procedure for this?

there should be a validation to check whether the record is already exists in next table also

Comment: show what you tried ?

Comment: Have you tried to use trigger ?

Comment: I have not written a stored procedure as this requirement prompts recently  and i do have no idea on how to start. As i could remember i thought of writing a stored procedure

Comment: @KuldipMCA Not yet. As mentioned in above comment i have no idea to start this.

Comment: can i ask if there is a good reason that this data is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger TRG_Insert_fDebtor on ABC.fDebtor
ON AFTER Insert
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --- checking for the record exist in the DEF database 
    IF (select count(*) from DEF.fDebtor where exists(select * from inserted)) > 0
    begin
        ----- insert record in your other database  DEF
        insert into DEF.fDebtor values ()
    end
end
```

Try trigger like that made changes as you need that's just approach you can use.